# Trying to make Battleships, having a problem

Tags: python-3.x

I keep getting the error message "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Here is the code:

```
def gap(): # generates a bunch of blank lines in the console to hide previous moves
    for i in range(30):
        print("")

def grid(): # The Grid that the game is in
    t = [] # the name of the actual grid list
    grid_size = 10 # self explanitory
    for i in range(grid_size): # this is called a for loop
        row = []
        for q in range(grid_size):
            row.append(" ")
        t.append(row)

    def move_player_1():      
      while True:
        gap()
        for i in range(len(t)):# this is called a for loop
            print(t[i])
            print('')
          #try:
        print("Choose what Ship to place")
        print('')
        print('')
        print("Write '2' for two long ship")
        print('')
        print("Write '3' for three long ship")
        print('')
        print("Write '4' for four long ship")
        print('')
        print("Write '5' for five long ship")
        print('')
            
            
        ship_length = int(input("Your Ship choice:"))
            
        placement_chords = input("player 1 (place ships) eg: 1,7 : ")
        row, col = placement_chords.split(",") # divides "move" into separate integers for row and column
        print(row)
        print(col)
        
        counter = 0
        for i in range(ship_length):
          t[row][counter],[col] = "0"
          print(t)
          counter += 1


        row, col = placement_chords.split(",")
        row -= 1 # this just subtracts one to fix things, if a player selected  the coordanates "1,1" it would actully happen on 2,2 because lists are weird
        col -=1
          
        if t[row][col] == " ": # hit detection
            t[row][col] = "x"
        else:
            print("HIT!")
        gap()
  
        for i in range(len(t)):# this is called a for loop and it is printing the       board  
          print(t[i])
          
        return t
            
          #except ValueError:
            #print("You have done it wrong")
            #time.sleep(2)
    
    move_player_1()#this is a definition
    
  
grid()
```

I was expecting the relevant positions to be filled as 0's to act as ships for battleships

Comment: This type of error message is very easy to debug. Did you use a debugger to set a breakpoint, and inspect variables? What did you find?

Answer (score 0):

This is the problematic line

```
      t[row][counter],[col] = "0"
```

The comma indicates that you would want to make two assignments, one to `t[row][counter]` and one to `[col]`. That makes no sense, and is not what you intended to do. This should just be:

```
      t[row][counter] = "0"
```

However, to make sure that this starts filling up from `col` onwards, you should initialise `counter` not to 0, but to `col`, so:

```
    counter = col  # start at the given column
    for i in range(ship_length):
      t[row][counter] = "0"
      print(t)
      counter += 1
```

Still this can give problems if the user inputs a column that is too far to the right of the grid. In that case the loop will increase `counter` to a value that is out of range. So you would need to add a check on whether the input is  valid in that sense.

Speaking of validation of input. Your code does not covert the input to number. So `row` and `col` are strings, but they should be numbers. In case you need numeric input, always convert the input to `int`. You can use `map` to apply this conversion to all the input values:

```
    row, col = map(int, placement_chords.split(","))
```

You don't need to perform the split twice. So remove that second call to spit -- you already have the values of `row` and `col`...

There is much more to improve in your code, but that is outside the scope of your current question.

Comment: thank you so much! This kind of works now, pretty much just a small formatting problem that I can probably figure out